# Whats the Name of this Signal-Filter

Tags: c, algorithm, moving-average

to get a moving average like filter on ADC data in microcontrollers, i like to use the following code:

```
average = average + ((new_value - average)>>2);
```

it works nicely and super fast and I can adjust the filterstrength just by changing the amount of right-shift.

My question is now: has this filter a name?

cheers :)

Comment: IDK its name, but its characteristic is that it responds to a spike in the input data faster than it recovers. Quick isn't always good.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between [Cumulative Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average) and [Weighted Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average)

Comment: thanks for the hint! 
so comparing my code with the cumulative moving average equations. It seems like I'm doing exactly that. with n+1 = 4 (2 times rightshift is a division with 4)
so i should get a average over the last 4 values, right?

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, it can be a specific case of [Savitzky-Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) method as well. It is a low pass filter with the following explantion:

> A Savitzky–Golay filter is a digital filter that can be applied to a set of digital data points for the purpose of smoothing the data, that is, to increase the precision of the data without distorting the signal tendency. This is achieved, in a process known as convolution, by fitting successive sub-sets of adjacent data points with a low-degree polynomial by the method of linear least squares. When the data points are equally spaced, an analytical solution to the least-squares equations can be found, in the form of a single set of "convolution coefficients" that can be applied to all data sub-sets, to give estimates of the smoothed signal, (or derivatives of the smoothed signal) at the central point of each sub-set.